# How to convert tabs to indents in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, text-formatting

When copy pasting text from another editor to microsoft word, paragraphs come with tabs in the beginning.
How to convert those to paragraph indents, to get better formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way I found to do that was to write a VBA macro.

It's probably not optimized for performance, but it does the job. =)

```
Sub ConvertLeadingTabsToIndents()
    On Error GoTo Error

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim found As Boolean

    found = FindNextTab()
    While (found)
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        Selection.TypeBackspace
        Selection.Paragraphs.Indent

        found = FindNextTab()
    Wend

    MsgBox "Success!", vbInformation

Exit_Sub:
    Exit Sub

Error:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ' Regenerate original error.
    Dim intErrNum As Integer
    intErrNum = Err
    Err.Clear
    Err.Raise intErrNum
End Sub

Function FindNextTab()
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p^t"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
    End With
    FindNextTab = Selection.Find.Execute
End Function
```

Comment: First-thankyou Renato!
This worked the first time, now returns an error (word 2007)-any clues?

    Err.Raise intErrNum 'X SEE HELP-NEED SOMETHING MORE-"application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Hey @Piecevcake. Unfortunatelly I don't have Word 2007. In Word 2013 and 365 the macro work. Can you execute it line by line to see where the error begins (where it jumps to `Error:`)? Also check the value of `Err` when it's there. That might help to indicate what can be causing this. Another option is to remove the lines `On Error GoTo Error` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, and see if the real error is shown

Comment: it says error 5962, the debug highlights FindNextTab = Selection.Find.Execute

Comment: FIX= add into function  With Selection.Find
.MatchWildcards = False